# How can I use HTML from an email template in a Quote Template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, html, cpq, quote-template

We have a custom email template built using HTML. I am trying to create a VisualForce component, using the same exact HTML, that I can then use into a CPQ quote template.

I removed any messaging tags that are used for emails. But I get a Error:

> Unknown property 'relatedTo'

I haven't changed what the code is trying to relate to, it's still a `Quote2__r`. Does `relatedTo` work differently in email templates than it does in plain VisualForce?

Answer (score 0):

To your question, *Does relatedTo work differently in email templates than it does in plain VisualForce?*

the answer is Yes. relatedTo attribute in email template sends the record detail from the email to the vf component. If you want to use the email template html as the quote template, copying the entire email template html to the quote template is not going to solve the purpose. you will have to update the quote template- html at some level